# gulp watch does not trigger on nfs share

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

I have a problem that gulp watch does not trigger in my setup. In my case I have web project running in a virtual machine.

Hostmachine: MAC OSX
Guestmachine: Ubuntu Server

The Project files live on the host machine and I use NFS to share the files with the guest machine in the /var/www/project folder.

When I run gulp watch on the host machine everything works fine, but I would prefer running it on the guest machine because I want to user browsersync, which I can't get running from the host machine with a web server on the guest machine.
When I run gulp watch on the guest machine, gulp starts normally and also runs the initial sass tasks but gulp watch never triggers on any changes.
When I copy the shared project files to my home folder on the guest machine a run gulp watch there, everything is working great again.
So it seems that the Problem is because of the NFS Share but i don't know why. I already tried setting different permissions but with no success.

Any Idea what wrong? Maybe someone has also a solution that I can run browsersync from the host machine, but I think this is not possible.

Below you can see the Code from my gulp file:

```js
// Defining dependencies
var
  gulp = require('gulp'),
  sass = require('gulp-sass'),
  postcss = require('gulp-postcss'),
  autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer'),
  sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

// Defining style function
function style() {
  return (
    gulp
      .src('css/**/**.scss')
      // Initialize souremaps before compilation starts
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      // Compile sass to css
      .pipe(sass())
      // Error handler for compilation errors
      .on('error', sass.logError)
      // Use postcss with autoprefixer
      .pipe(postcss([autoprefixer()]))
      // Now add/write the sourcemaps
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
      // Add browsersync stream pipe after compilation
  );
}
exports.style = style;

// Define gulp watcher function
function watch() {
  style();

  // Run style function on sass changes
  gulp.watch('css/**/*.scss', style);
}
exports.watch = watch;

// Define default task
exports.default = watch;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself. The problem is that the file system notifications are not forwarded from the host to the guest, which should trigger gulp watch.

You can use https://github.com/mhallin/notify-forwarder to solve this problem.